# Issue with sed , aliasing and quotes

Tags: shell, sed, alias

I am new to shell programming

I have a command `sed -i '$d' ~/.bash_history` which works fine.I wanted to Alias it so I wrote it as

```
alias rh='sed -i "$d" ~/.bash_history'
```

When I execute `rh` it executes without error but does not delete anything from the file.I have a feeling that it has to do with the quotes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash calculates value of "$d" and replace it by "" if $d is not defined. 
Try this:

```
alias rh='sed -i '\''$d'\'' ~/.bash_history'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a function makes the quoting easier:

```
rh () { sed -i '$d' ~/.bash_history; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to implement an hybrid solution equivalent to:

```
alias rh='function _rh(){ sed -i '\''$d'\'' ~/.bash_history ; };_rh'
```